# Snowflake copy from s3 with jdbc but no load status

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to loaded data from s3 to snowflake with jdbc using following command:

```
copy into <target_table> from <s3_bucket> credentials=(aws_key_id='' aws_secret_key='') file_format = (format_name = 'my_csv') FORCE = TRUE ON_ERROR = SKIP_FILE;
```

The load status wrote when data load successfully. But when data copy failed, load status didn't write and return "0 rows affected, copy executed successfully"

If I ran same command in web UI, the load status write successfully.

I used snowflake jdbc version 3.9.2 and 3.11.0.

Can someone please help me resolve this? Thanks in advance.

---

Updated: After commit the copy command, status is loaded into load_history table.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that this same COPY INTO command works via the UI, but gives an error "0 rows affected" when trying via JDBC?  That error can mean that no new data was found.  Can you double-check that there is data to be loaded and the path is correct?  You may wish to try the fully qualified path to the table as well.

Comment: Some ideas: Check the S3 path as Snowflake doesn't return an error if no files match.  You can use VALIDATION_MODE = RETURN_10_ROWS to debug.  If you create a stage, you can LIST the S3 files that snowflake can see.

Comment: Hi @Suzy Lockwood, yes, you understand right. I'm sure there is data to be loaded and path is correct. Also for table path, I used "database_name"."schema_name"."table_name", but it's not working.

Comment: Hi @waldente, I tried validation_mode, it return errors as I expected. But when ran normal copy into command, it didn't write load status into load_history or copy_history table.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same role when logging in via JDBC as you are when using the web UI? Can you provide the code for both instances?

Comment: You could also try testing with SnowSQL or moving the files to a stage first from S3, then loading from the stage.  It might help narrow down where the issue is.